# What libs exist to test .Net MVC Routes?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I found several questions on StackOverflow wondering what libraries or what best practices. Are all very usable for noobs, help me a lot.

What libs exist to test .Net MVC Routes?

I found Fluent route tester in [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) where i got some problems to test with PostMethods.

Exist another librarys like MVCContrib to test Routes?

**Update:**

I say Test a .Net MVC Routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Usuario", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Librarys to test if my routes are triggered correct if I call: "~/controller/action".

Comment: I think you may be getting close to the "Gorilla vs. Shark" (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) area where this is a little broad. You should probably consider narrowing the scope of what you're asking, or clarifying exactly what you're trying to do. Unit test a route? Debug routes at runtime? Create and test your own route handlers?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like and use [MvcContrib.TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) which among many things also you to [unit test your routes](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper#Routes). I never had problems testing any routes or controller actions with it.

Comment: See my problem with MvcContrib.TestHelper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164967/mvccontrib-test-helper-and-verifying-http-post-routes-and-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about unit tests or during development? For the second check Phil Hacks Route Debugger [Link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Comment: Unit test of URLRoutes in .Net MVC.